# singleton + global mysqli

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, singleton

Есть сложный сайт, сам писал, работает в основном на php+mysqli+ajax. 
Проблема в том что обрабатывает весь сайт 1 файл, functions.php
Как не трудно догадаться файл состоит из функций, а внутри каждой функции стоит подключение к БД. 
Задумал с помощью auto_prepend_file подключать конфиг , где будет singleton для mysqli.

Вопрос собственно в том можно ли объявить mysqli подключение глобально , что бы внутри функций не подключать каждый раз файл конфига и БД.
Хочется снизить максимальное количество подключений хотя бы до 5 , а то с 10 ели ели пашет все.

Comment: поэтому видимо и сложный, что в одном файле все, да?

Comment: @teran 24 сложный потому что очень много возможностей, и почти все делают запросы к БД , последнее время начал смотреть в сторону кэширования БД. Там более 20к функций , и все каждый раз подключают файл конфига и БД. Надо исправить( Благо существует sublime и Ctrl+H

Comment: Ну так подключиться один раз в начале файла да и всё, не?

Comment: @andreymal не не, вы что :) надо поддерживать большой объем и сложность :)